# Android AlertDialog List

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am creating an `AlertDialog` with a list of items.
Image of what is currently shown:

[image: AlertDialog]

I want to make the category list items to be in bold.
Is there a way to do this?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Make a choice from the list:");
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setItems(R.array.items_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selection: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: mb you should create custom alterdialog with your own layout

Comment: With a custom alert dialog would I be able to have multiple category items, and multiple child items under the category

Comment: ListView, ExpandetListView... you may add it to custom layout. It has titles...

Comment: Thank you. I used ExpandableListView for the solution.

Comment: enjoy! I post my answer with ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ExpandableListView even though you just want headers.  For one of my projects I had the exact same issue involving headers, and I had to create a custom adapter for it.

First create a new class with something like...

```
    public class MyCustomListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
```

These are my "getChildView" and "getGroupView" from my project...

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    DetailInfo detailInfo = (DetailInfo) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
    }
    TextView childItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.childItem);
    childItem.setText(detailInfo.getName().trim());

    return view;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    HeaderInfo headerInfo = (HeaderInfo) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_heading, null);
    }

    TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
    heading.setText(headerInfo.getName().trim());

    return view;
}
```

So now, you have complete control over what gets displayed as the group or child.  In this case, the group gets displayed as a header, and the children as the data.

Here is a screenshot of what my listview looks like with this code...

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

Use this [**ExpandableListView** tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) to solve your problem:
[image]